# Jmeter scenario

Tags: jmeter

Initial load vu Ramp up 1 (after 5 min) Ramp up 2 (after 10 min) Ramp up 3(after 10 min)

200 vu +50 vu +50 vu +120 vu

how to implement this scenario in jmeter. is this psbl in Jmeter, kindly help professionals

Comment: Do you want to increase user in each ramp up?

Comment: yes i want to increase user in each ramp up

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the easiest option is using [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/).

It provides easy visual way of defining the load pattern

[image: Ultimate Thread Group]

If you for some reason don't have possibility to use this solution you can achieve the same by the combination of:

- [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)
- [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
- [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action)
- And proper settings of threads and rampup on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level.